# Separate code from existing plugin - Shopware

Tags: shopware

I've made some code changes to the frontend of an existing Shopware plugin. How do I separate the files I've made changes to from the original plugin? Just to avoid that it will get overwritten when the plugin is updated.

Answer (score 1):

this depends on the changes you have made to the plugin. Generally speaking, you have to create your own plugin.
Now you could try to extend the plugin with the same functions you would extend the Shopware core with.

Here you could find a documentation about how to extend the Custom Products plugin https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/plugin-extension-by-plugin/

The same applies to other plugins. Use events of the plugins, use the Symfony decorator pattern or the Shopware event and hook system.

The easiest thing would be template changes. Just register your template directory and recreate the template structure of the plugin you want to extend. Just as you would do, if you want to extend the core.

Hope this helps for the moment

Best regards from Schöppingen

Michael Telgmann